Code splitting javascript files in vue with webpack not working
Vue 3.5.11
I am using the pinia npm package to use stores in my vue app. I have been doing it the synchronous way:
<script setup>
 import { storeToRefs } from "pinia";
 import { usePhotoApi } from "@/composables/photos";
 const state = usePhotoApi();
 const { info, errored, loading } = storeToRefs(state);
  onMounted(()=>{
   Promise.all([state.getPhotos()]).then(() => {
    console.log("form fields are", info.value);
  });
})
</script>

My photos.js file is this:
  import { defineStore } from "pinia";

  export const usePhotoApi = defineStore("photos", {
    state: () => ({
      info: null,
      loading: true,
      errored: false
    }),
    actions: {
      async getPhotos() {
         //get my photos
    },
  });

This works fine, but it can be better optimized. I found this: https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/07/03/vue-js-code-splitting-webpack/ and I now have the following:
<script setup>
  import { storeToRefs } from "pinia";
  const usePhotoApi = () => import("@/composables/photos.js");
  const state = await usePhotoApi()
  const { info, errored, loading } = storeToRefs(state);
  onMounted(()=>{
   Promise.all([state.getPhotos()]).then(() => {
    console.log("form fields are", info.value);
   });
  })

 </script>

Now, I get an error:
 state.getPhotos is not a function 

There are no other errors, just the one above. What is the correct syntax (or way) to call methods from my javascript using code splitting like the article outlines? Thanks

The error is because store module was used incorrectly. import() returns a promise of module object, which needs to be destructured to get named export. And this await usePhotoApi() doesn't make sense, pinia stores don't return promises.  It likely should be const { usePhotoApi } = await import("@/composables/photos.js"). It's unknown if this serves a good purpose. The article discusses dynamically loaded components, that's where this makes sense. A store doesn't look like the optional part that could be loaded later, not to mention that it's footprint is small

@EstusFlask - the syntax you provided worked. I got the data like before. And you are correct, for a store, this may not be pertinent, but all I wanted to learn was the correct syntax to use code splitting because I have other js files/components I need to load this way

Glad it worked. Notice that "await" in setup requires to handle async component with , this part isn't covered by the article because it dates from before vue 3. Also in practice it's enough to split at the route, this makes lazily loaded routes a convenient feature
